# Haskell Mini-Interpreter

Tags: haskell, interpreter

So our prof presented us with this code and two questions about it. I have no clue where to even begin because I do not understand any of the code presented, so just understanding what all these lines are doing is a good start.

I know `data` is to declare data types and the `|` acts as an Or.

But for everything else such as `Lambda String Exp`, 
is it a `String` or an anonymous function and is `Exp` a pre-defined value?
What are the `VLambda` and the `VVar` supposed to be?
Going with an explanation of every line would be great.
Thank you for your time :)

Here is some Haskell code that serves as an interpreter of a functional mini-language:

```
-- The expressions

data Exp = Var String
   | Lambda String Exp
   | App Exp Exp

-- The values returned by the interpreter

data Value = VVar String
   | VLambda String Exp
type Env = [(String, Value)]

-- The interpreter

eval :: Env -> Exp -> Value
eval env e = ...
```

1. Which scope will be used by the function eval?
2. What do we have to change to allow for the other scope?

The scopes referred to are either dynamic or static(lexical) scope

Comment: Sounds like you don't know how to read `data` declarations yet.  [This](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) might help

Comment: so it's not *Haskell* Mini-interpreter, it's *a* Mini-interpreter coded *in* Haskell.

Comment: @WillNess it has lambdas, so if you squint you could call it a mini Haskell mini interpreter (in haskell)

Comment: It looks like your professor is rushing ahead of you on the learning curve - by the time you implement an interpreter, you would normally have your students be pretty comfortable with type definitions. I would recommend that you review earlier materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of questions in one here, and StackOverflow works better when you ask one specific question per post. Anyways, here's a start:

> `Lambda String Exp`, is it a String or an anonymous function

It's a value with the non-special name "Lambda" that contains a `String` and an `Exp`. It's the equivalent of this Java class:

```
class Lambda extends Exp {
  String variable;
  Exp expression;
}
```

It represents an anonymous function expression in the interpreted language.

> is `Exp` a pre-defined value?

No, it's defined right here in your snippet, `data Exp = ...`

> What are the VLambda and the VVar supposed to be?

The interpreter uses different types for an expression and a resulting value, so a `Lambda` expression would evaluate into a `VLambda` value, and a `Var` expression into either a `Value` from the environment or a `VVar` if it's free (presumably). An `App` expression would be evaluated until you get a `Value`

> Which scope will be used by the function eval?

The `eval` function will evaluate a language with dynamic scoping. You can tell because the VLambda does not have an Env field that could store the closure.

> What do we have to change to allow for the other scope?

You'd add an Env field to the VLambda that will store the closure of lexical variables when the Lambda was evaluated.